# Simple Json Request never succeeds

Tags: node.js, ajax, express

I have a very simple Express server with a single route. I want to call this route with ajax from my html page and return json to the page.

The server side function gets called successfully but the failure method of the ajax method gets called the whole time. It never succeeds.

**NodeJs**

```
app.get('/test', function(req, res) {
  console.log("TEST WAS CALLED");// This Logs to Console
  res.json({ message: 'Hello World' });
});
```

**Client Ajax**

```
function FetchData(callbackfn) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "http://localhost:3000/test",
        async:false,
        cache:false,
        success: function (data) {
            callbackfn(data)
        },
        error: function (textStatus, errorThrown) {
          console.log(errorThrown);
          console.log(textStatus);
            callbackfn("Error getting the data")
        }

    });
}

function Callback(data) {
    alert(data);
}
```

Comment: What is logged to the console?

Comment: TEST WAS CALLED
GET /test?_=1495113115862 200 4.727 ms - 25

Comment: Have you tried PostMan for chrome? First principles approach will determine if your server call is valid. I doubt it. Probably some error code is returning from the server even if console works.

Comment: good suggestion thanks. I'll try that now

Comment: How do you call it?

Comment: The request works fine in postman. The simple json is returned

Comment: Like `FetchData( Callback )`?

Comment: @MohitBhardwaj I'm calling the method from window.onload in my html file. And Yes I call it as above

Comment: try using getJSON you're probably messing up the ajax call

Comment: If the app is not being served from `localhost:3000`, this is probably a CORS problem.

Comment: Try `console.log(data)` as the first line in your success handler and see what you get.

Comment: My question is what is being logged to the console by the client app--you know, by the `console.log(errorThrown)` statement. If nothing is being logged, that means that the code did not arrive there. How are you calling `FetchData`? It's possibly an error is occurring when trying to invoke the callback from the success branch. Also, consult the network tab of devtools to see what the response it (status and content).

Comment: @torazaburo DevTools shows the following error "XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:3000/test?_=1495114932060. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access."

Comment: As I suspected, it's CORS. Google for that.

Comment: @torazaburo cors fixed it. If you'd like to add an answer I'll accept it as correct